# Vega-lite: customize axis style based on selection

Tags: vega-lite, vega

I'm trying to customize the style of axis labels based on a selection, meaning whether the label is included in a selection or not.

Starting from this demo spec ([Open the Chart in the Vega Editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoBG2VxBaEAGU4q+Uog79aAIwAmAL4KTZi1YBhNgYcOEUQJ0EXVFcABm9fc0t0axw2ACdMCAACKCR08MjogGYAVgSQUySra3VMdllsgHckMjlC5wNUADYATgqq-3QACTVYJiQoAGsOqK7e1wG-ZJAg2VJMmiYo2ejS4qXqlLTM-gZ64UwAT2zSGBooHcdOtzFDoZAAWRpZGm0HCIvVBiAAcngAut5KvkZugJgVHBY4FB6u1NBEkSiAPqDZKga6hKwQH5kJ4gABmNAsyi6hkqyxAkKhcFkUDMJLQoCunIpVMEyisuJAUIAHjzKdSiS8lASwugAI4MJCyep1P5hKGUwSCADyOEmdG56O0ujlsUoxSUbNkyjoDR5EExqPk6EdUWxQqUJr0bk8fs8QA)) the selection works as expected, highlighting the selected bar:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      { "model": "Sedan",                 "sales": 12 },
      { "model": "Coupe",                 "sales": 10 },
      { "model": "Sports car",            "sales": 35 },
      { "model": "Station wagon",         "sales": 69 },
      { "model": "Hatchback",             "sales": 91 },
      { "model": "Convertible",           "sales": 53 },
      { "model": "Sport-utility vehicle", "sales": 14 },
      { "model": "Minivan",               "sales": 48 }
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "selection": {
    "select_model": { "type": "single", "fields": ["model"] }
  },
  "encoding": {
    "y": { "field": "model" },
    "x": { "field": "sales", "type": "quantitative" },
    "fillOpacity": {
      "value": 0.3,
      "condition": { "selection": "select_model", "value": 1 }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

But I would like to highlight the axis labels too (and maybe accept clicks on them? I'm not sure if that's possible)

If I try to replace the Y encoding with this:

```json
"y": { 
  "field": "model",
  "axis": {
    "labelOpacity": {
      "value": 0.3,
      "condition": { 
        "test": { "selection": "select_model" }, 
        "value": 1 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot read property 'getSelectionComponent' of null

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your approach did not work is because scale labels are never contained in selections. You can accomplish what you want by explicitly testing if the label is present in the selected values using a [vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/). It might look something like this:

```json
      "axis": {
        "labelOpacity": {
          "value": 0.3,
          "condition": {
            "test": "indexof(select_model.model || [], datum.value) >= 0",
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      }
```

This is the full result ([view in editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JACyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUMSSCGcCGgDaoBG2VxBaEAGU4q+Uog79aAIwAmAL4KTZi1YBhNgYcOEUQJ0EXVFcABm9fc0t0axw2ACdMCAACKCR08MjogGYAVgSQUySra3VMdllsgHckMjlC5wNUADYATgqq-3QACTVYJiQoAGsOqK7e1wG-ZJAg2VJMmiYo2ejS4qXqlLTM-gZ64UwAT2zSGBooHcdOtzFDoZAAWRpZGm0HCIvVBiAAcngAut5KvkZugJgVHBY4FB6u1NBEkSiAPqDZKga6hKwQH5kJ4gABmNAsyi6hkqyxA4KUiBw1yssjkYU8UMw6SQsgg5IyCCMoDygigDEEajC6B+5gAHmxyQAKCCYzA45aUXHZAA+euyhiZ2QA5KNMONJlNTQBKcJILogABqOhAEOZsigZhJaFAVz9FKpgmUVlxDoVNC6oGlTAsAHkcJM6AH0dpdLLYpRikpvbJlHQGoHMPpMFZ5XAlar1VFsbidct9YbjQpsqpMAwEJR03pbdkAHwAXmysXCPdli25UIVgcp1KJLyUBNlIAAjgx+fU6n8uUpKYJBInk2y0zo9GgszmQHmC6j5Oia8i70SNVrqkpx24p54gA)):

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v4.json",
  "data": {
    "values": [
      {"model": "Sedan", "sales": 12},
      {"model": "Coupe", "sales": 10},
      {"model": "Sports car", "sales": 35},
      {"model": "Station wagon", "sales": 69},
      {"model": "Hatchback", "sales": 91},
      {"model": "Convertible", "sales": 53},
      {"model": "Sport-utility vehicle", "sales": 14},
      {"model": "Minivan", "sales": 48}
    ]
  },
  "mark": "bar",
  "selection": {
    "select_model": {"type": "single", "fields": ["model"], "empty": "none"}
  },
  "transform": [
    {"calculate": "indexof(select_model.model || [], 'Hatchback')", "as": "Val"}
  ],
  "encoding": {
    "y": {
      "field": "model",
      "axis": {
        "labelOpacity": {
          "value": 0.3,
          "condition": {
            "test": "indexof(select_model.model || [], datum.value) >= 0",
            "value": 1
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "x": {"field": "sales", "type": "quantitative"},
    "fillOpacity": {
      "value": 0.3,
      "condition": {"selection": "select_model", "value": 1}
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh, I see. Time to study Vega expression language, I guess. Thank you for always helping me!